# Java: Hide my IP when using a (transparent) HTTP Proxy

Tags: java, http, proxy, request, socks

How can I hide my IP when I use a (transparent) HTTP proxy in Java?

System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "..."); did not do the work for me. When testing with an transparent HTTP proxy, I see my real IP and not the Socks Proxy IP.

Any ideas?

If I was not clear enough:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, ...);
URLConnection conn = new URL("...").openConnection(proxy);
```

If "proxy" has a transparent HTTP Proxy, the IP of a Socks Proxy should be shown and not my real IP. I know that you could set "proxy" with Proxy.Type.SOCKS and use a Socks Proxy, but Socks Proxies are much harder to find.

Comment: You see your real IP address where?

Comment: Several websites, e.g. myip.is shows you if you are connected through a transparent proxy.